# Java multiple function call

Tags: java

If in Java , I am making an object of class P and then I am calling two function of that class like this -

> P pop=new pop()
>
> pop.getfit().fitness()

I wanted to know what will happen, will both functions be called? or will they be called one by one?

Comment: It would take less time to test yourself than posting here.. tried that ?

Comment: getfit then  fitness

Comment: Given the nature of this question I'm not even sure this will compile

Answer (score 2):

It'll probably show an error unless pop.getfit() returns an object, if it returns an object and the object has a method called fitness (), the fitness() of the returned object will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

if both getfit() and fitness() are member of pop ,then  its depend upon what value return by getfit(). 
if getfit() return pop object then call to fitness() is valid otherwise it would be a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Both function will be called one by one, but call to the `fitness()` will depend on the output of the `pop.getfit()` function. Call to `fitness()` function will give compilation error if the output of `pop.getfit()` is not an object of the class, the function `fitness()` belongs to.

Let's understand this with a different example:

```
class MainTest{
    Test t;
    public Test test_object(){
        t = new Test();
        return t;
    }
}
class Test{
    int x;
    public Test(){
        x = 10;
    } 
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int sum(int a, int b){
        return (a+b);
    }
    public void printHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
    }   
}
class multiple_call{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainTest t = new MainTest();
        int sum = t.test_object().sum(1, 3);
        System.out.println(sum); // runs perfectly as output of t.test_object() is an object of Test class, then its sum function is called. 

        // Test test = new Test();
        // test.getX().printHello(); // compilation error: void cannot be dereferenced

    }
}
```